# Can Lucio's Speed Boost Increase Fire Rate?

Tags: overwatch

I want to assume the answer is no and that I'm just going crazy. I just lost a match in which a Reaper, in the kill cam, seemed to be firing much faster, as well as moving faster. There was a Lucio using speed boost at the time. Is Lucio ever able to increase fire rate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You can see from his abilities breakdown [here](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/L%C3%BAcio#Ability_Breakdown) and [here](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/heroes/lucio/) that it will only increase movement speed. The key phrase from the official site is 
He can switch between two songs: **one amplifies movement speed**, while the other regenerates health.

Comment: Okay, that answers it. Just wanted to make sure i wasn't going crazy.